# program of different ratio of android screen device

Tags: java, android

currently, I was work in my emulator which was 3.2in HVGA. it will display same size of content in the 3.2inch device but it will different size of content in the different screen ratio android device?

my question is, how to set the content fit the different screen ratio and display same size of content in all different screen ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about specifics but to scale app to different screen sizes I added following in my manifest and it worked as a charm.

> ```
>  <supports-screens
>     android:smallScreens="true"
>     android:normalScreens="true"
>     android:largeScreens="true"
>     android:resizeable="true"
>     android:anyDensity="true" />
> ```

Comment: i did so, hope can work too, hard to find different size screen only got 2 types

Answer (score 0):

You should use different folders for storing your layouts for different resolutions. For example, for and hdpi layout you should use the layout-hdpi folder. You can rename any resources folder this way and store different resources there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep your "markup" fluid (use fill_parent, weight and those type of attributes, vs fixed ones) and use density independent pixels (`dip`s) you should have no problem supporting any sort of screen resolution/orientation combinations. Remember you can create as many virtual devices as you want (with different screen resolutions/dimensions) to test out your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use DIP (Density Independent Pixels) as the font size unit. e.g.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="This is sample text" android:textSize="18dip"/>
```

Note that textSize value is 18 DIP. It will be converted by android into actual pixels for each device so you don't have to worry about text size anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In my apps I rarely use dip. I mostly make use layout_weight property for linear layouts and wrap content and fillparent properties of layouts.
Giving fixed values for layouts is a bad idea in android.